# Manipulate multiple files by inode

Tags: command-line, inode

I have a large number of files that contain backslashes `\` that I would like to manipulate, but whenever I try something like:

```
$ ls -li
2036553851 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6757 May 20 00:10 Simplex_config\\B1:B3\\_1.csv
2036553766 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6756 May 20 00:07 Simplex_config\\B1:B3\\_2.csv
2036554099 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6785 May 20 00:20 Simplex_config\\B1:B3\\_3.csv
2036553974 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 6785 May 20 00:15 Simplex_config\\B1:B3\\_4.csv

$ find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' | xargs cat > looksee.txt
```

I receive a `No such file or directory` error. I have considered changing the filenames and then manipulating, but I am curious to see if there was an easier solution with the `inode`.

I came up with:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -f looksee.txt ]; then
   rm -rf looksee.txt
fi

ls -i Simplex_config*.csv | awk '{ print $1 }' > inode_list.txt

while IFS= read -r inode;
do
  find . -inum $inode -exec cat {} \; >> looksee.txt
done < inode_list.txt
```

But this is very cumbersome and I would like to try to find a way to parse the output from `ls -i Simplex_config*.csv` and pipe it to another command in a one-liner -- is there such an option available?

Comment: Try `find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > looksee.txt` or even `find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -exec cat {} + > looksee.txt`

Comment: @Costas perfect, would you mind making that an answer and explaining why the `-print0`/`-0` in the first and the `+` in the second make this possible?

Comment: And if `ls Simplex_config*.csv` have enough recursion for you why do you do not use `cat Simplex_config*.csv >  looksee.txt`

Comment: @Costas in the toy example this would be enough, but in the true situation I would have to resolve recursion. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > looksee.txt
```

From **man xargs**

> **--null**
>       **-0**
>   Input items are terminated by a null character instead of by  whitespace,  and  the  quotes  and backslash  are  not  special  (every  character  is  taken literally).  Disables the end of file string, which is treated like any other argument.  Useful when input items might  contain  white space,  quote  marks,  or  backslashes.  The GNU `find -print0` option produces input suitable for this mode.

2.

```
find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -exec cat {} + > looksee.txt
```

From **man find**

> **-exec command ;**
>   Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following arguments to find are taken to  be arguments to the command until an argument consisting of `;` is encountered.  The string `{}` is replaced by the current file name being processed everywhere it occurs in the arguments  to  the command,  not  just  in arguments where it is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions might need to be escaped (with a `\`) or quoted to protect them from expansion  by the shell. The specified command is run once for each matched file.  The command is executed in the  starting  directory. There  are unavoidable security problems surrounding use of the *-exec* action; you should use the *-execdir* option instead.
>
> **-exec command {} +**
>   This variant of the *-exec* action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the  command  line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its command lines.  Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.

3.

```
cat Simplex_config* > looksee.txt
```

if you have 1 level of subpath only.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access files by inodes, because that would break access control via permissions. For example, if you don't have the permission to traverse a directory, then you can't access any of the files in that directory no matter what the permissions on the file are. If you could access a file by inode, that would bypass directory permissions.

Thus, while you can obtain a file's device and inode numbers, you need to find a path to the file in order to act on it. (*A* path, not *the* path, since there can be more than one if the file has multiple hard links.) This means that if you use inodes, you'll always have more work to do. The only reason to even look at inodes is if you want to be aware of hard links and act only once on each file with multiple hard links.

Your `find` command is easily fixed by either using `-print0` and `xargs -0` (if available on your system), or using the `-exec` action. For more information, see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

```
find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -exec cat {} + > looksee.txt
find . -type f -name 'Simplex*.csv' -print0 | xargs -0 cat > looksee.txt
```

Comment: Why do you say that accessing a file via its inode would bypass the permissions on that inode? I can imagine an 'open_inode' syscall that would respect the inode's mode just as 'open' does. What's impossible about that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'directory permissions'? Are you referring to the mode of an inode? Dirents don't have anything I would call 'permissions'.

Comment: @AnotherSmellyGeek By “directory permissions”, I mean the permissions on directories. For example, you can't access `/dir/file` if you don't have the `x` permission on `/dir`, regardless of the permissions stored in the inode for `/dir/file`.

Comment: Yep, I think when you say "permissions on directories", you mean the mode of an inode. Don't you? Separately, I don't understand what the ability or inability to traverse parent directories has to do with bypassing (or not bypassing) inodes' modes. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by 'access'. If /dir/file's inode were hard-linked into some other directory on which I did have traverse, and if the inode's mode permitted it, then I would be able to open(2) that inode by that other name, even if I didn't have traverse on /dir. Wouldn't you call that an "access"?

Comment: Oh, wait, do you mean the access(2) syscall?

Comment: @AnotherSmellyGeek “Permissions” and “mode” are synonymous in this context. By “access”, I mean do something with the content of the file, which under the hood means `open(2)`. For example, if you don't have `x` permissions to `/dir`, then there's no way you can access `/dir/file`, no matter what the permissions on `/dir/file` are (unless you can traverse some other directory where the file is hard-linked).

Answer (score 0):

@Costas already gave you the best answer, to replay to your second question

> But this is very cumbersome and I would like to try to find a way to parse the output from ls -i Simplex_config*.csv and pipe it to another command in a one-liner -- is there such an option available?

you can just use xargs:

```
ls -i | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | xargs -I '$input' find -inum '$input' -exec cat {} \;
```

the `-I` option let you specify a string to replace with what it reads from the stdin.

Comment: This is really bizzare: using `ls`, then `cut` then `find` the inode number. You can directly use `find` as explained by others.